# VBA If statements?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a load of IF statements but I'm 100% sure this can be done better and much shorter (cleaner).

I've been trying to use Google to find a solution but I couldn't find anything that suited my issue.

How can I make the following code cleaner and shorter?

```
Dim wsTab1 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab2 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab3 As Worksheet
Dim Array1 As Variant
Dim Array2 As Variant
Set wsTab1 = Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst")
Set wsTab2 = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen")
Set wsTab3 = Sheets("Tab 3 - Prijslijst aangepast")
Array1 = Array("DK", "DL", "DM", "DN", "DO", "DP", "DQ", "DR", "DS", "DT",         "DU", "DV", "DW", "DX", "DY", "DZ", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "CQ", "CR", "CS", "CT", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF", "DG", "DH", "DI", "DJ")
Array2 = Array("W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V")

For i = 0 To UBound(Array1) 'loop through array
If wsTab1.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value <> wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value Then 'do your comparison based on array values
    wsTab3.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value = wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value
    wsTab3.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
Next i
```

EDIT: managed to get this ^

Comment: Code that works but needs optimization belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  This site is for problematic code.  If your code does not work, please explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the ranges as Arrays of values for comparison purposes, something like the following:

Bear in mind that I've noticed that the second line after the IF Statement sometimes references xlCell2.Row and some other times it references xlCell3.Row, for simplicity I've just used xlCell2.Row, as it might be a mistake on your code?

```
Dim wsTab1 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab2 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab3 As Worksheet
Dim Array1 As Variant
Dim Array2 As Variant
Set wsTab1 = Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst")
Set wsTab2 = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen")
Set wsTab3 = Sheets("Tab 3 - Prijslijst aangepast")
Array1 = Array("DK", "DL", "DM", "DN", "DO", "DP", "DQ", "DR", "DS", "DT", "DU", "DV", "DW", "DX", "DY", "DZ", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "CQ", "CR", "CS", "CT", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF", "DG", "DH", "DI", "DJ")
Array2 = Array("W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V")

For i = 0 To UBound(Array1) 'loop through array
    If wsTab1.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value <> wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value Then 'do your comparison based on array values
        wsTab3.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value = wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Value
        wsTab3.Range(Array1(i) & xlCell2.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        wsTab2.Range(Array2(i) & xlCell2.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next i
```

**UPDATE**
Or you could do the same without using arrays at all by doing something like below:

```
Dim wsTab1 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab2 As Worksheet
Dim wsTab3 As Worksheet
Set wsTab1 = Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst")
Set wsTab2 = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen")
Set wsTab3 = Sheets("Tab 3 - Prijslijst aangepast")
For i = 95 To 134
    If wsTab1.Cells(i, xlCell2.Row).Value <> wsTab2.Cells(i - 92, xlCell2.Row).Value Then 'do your comparison based on array values
        wsTab3.Cells(i, xlCell2.Row).Value = wsTab2.Cells(i - 92, xlCell2.Row).Value
        wsTab3.Cells(i, xlCell3.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        wsTab2.Cells(i - 92, xlCell2.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Woah, never knew about the UBound code. Thanks alot!

Comment: There is also a LBound to give you the lowest as opposed to Ubound to give you the highest index of an array...

Answer (score 0):

I'll get you started - here's the first one (labelled 'Inkoopprijs in your code) - the others 'Inkoopstaffels etc will simplify thw same way

```
Sub demo2()

Dim wsTab1 As Worksheet
Set wsTab1 = Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst")
Dim wsTab2 As Worksheet
Set wsTab2 = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen")
Dim wsTab3 As Worksheet
Set wsTab3 = Sheets("Tab 3 - Prijslijst aangepast")
Dim c2Row As Long
Dim c3row As Long
c2Row = xlCell2.Row
c3row = xlCell3.Row
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

For x = 23 To 42  ' Cols W to AP
    y = x + 92
'Inkoopprijs
    If wsTab1.Cells(c2Row, y).Value <> wsTab2.Cells(c2Row, x).Value Then
        wsTab3.Cells(c2Row, y).Value = wsTab2.Cells(c2Row, x).Value
        wsTab3.Cells(c3row, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        wsTab2.Cells(c2Row, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: Pretty neat code, you're amazing. Thanks!